# Android throwing an exception while parsing data in list

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, xml-parsing, runtimeexception

I am parsing data through http client and parsing that data in a list using custom adapter.
where data is stored in an array, but while running I am getting exception and list not visible. my code is

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"

        />


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/li"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        ></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.httpwebservices;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    String url,Responce;
    Data data;
    ArrayList<Data> arrayUser;
    ArrayList<String> arrayofString;
    CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                        url=("http://japp.b4live.com/lectureme.asmx/GetIndividualUser");
                        arrayUser = new ArrayList<Data>();
                        new WebService().execute(url);
                        ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.li);                      




    }


    public class WebService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String...Arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                        HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost request=new HttpPost();
                        request.setURI(new URI(url));
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("skey","U082620130715346802"));
                        UrlEncodedFormEntity Entity=new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
                        request.setEntity(Entity);
                        HttpResponse responce=client.execute(request);
                        HttpEntity resEntity=responce.getEntity();

                        if(resEntity!=null)
                        {
                            Responce=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                            //Log.i("Responce",""+Responce);
                            parse(Responce);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            Log.i("Responce",""+Responce);
                        }
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                arrayofString=new ArrayList<String>();                  
                for(int i=0 ; i< arrayUser.size() ;i++)
                {
                    data=arrayUser.get(i);
                    arrayofString.add(data.getName());
                    Log.i("parsed", ""+data.getName());
                }   
                CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.Name, arrayofString);

                list.setAdapter(adapter);   

                Log.i("data parsed", ""+arrayofString.size());
                }



    }


    public void parse(String xml)
    {



        arrayUser=new ArrayList<Data>();
        Data d=null;

        try {

            boolean name=false,IndividualUser=false,id=false,initial=false,organisation=false,country=false,state=false,city=false,pincode=false,datecreated=false,datemodified=false,usertype=false,photol=false,following=false,followdt=false;

            XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser pullParser=factory.newPullParser();
            pullParser.setInput(new StringReader(xml));
            arrayUser=new ArrayList<Data>();
            int eventType=pullParser.getEventType();

            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                switch(eventType)
                {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("GetIndividualUser"))
                    {
                        IndividualUser=true;
                        d=new Data();
                    }
                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mbname"))
                    {
                        name=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
                    {
                        id=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Initial"))
                    {
                        initial=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("organization"))
                    {
                        organisation=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("country"))
                    {
                        country=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("state"))
                    {
                        state=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("city"))
                    {
                        city=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pincode"))
                    {
                        pincode=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("datecreated"))
                    {
                        datecreated=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("datemodified"))
                    {
                        datemodified=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("usertype_nm"))
                    {
                        usertype=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("photo1"))
                    {
                        photol=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("followflag"))
                    {
                        following=true;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("followdt"))
                    {
                        followdt=true;
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    if(name)
                    {
                        d.setName(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(city)
                    {
                        d.setCity(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(country)
                    {
                        d.setCountry(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(datecreated)
                    {
                        d.setDateCreated(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(datemodified)
                    {
                        d.setDateModified(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(followdt)
                    {
                        d.setFollowDate(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(following)
                    {
                        d.setFollowing(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(id)
                    {
                        d.setId(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(IndividualUser)
                    {
                        d.setindividualUser(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(initial)
                    {
                        d.setInitial(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(organisation)
                    {
                        d.setOrganisation(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(photol)
                    {
                        d.setPhoto(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(pincode)
                    {
                        d.setPincode(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(state)
                    {
                        d.setState(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    if(usertype)
                    {
                        d.setUserType(pullParser.getText().trim());

                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("GetIndividualUser"))
                    {
                        IndividualUser=false;
                        arrayUser.add(d);
                    }
                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("mbname"))
                    {
                        name=false;

                    }
                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
                    {
                        id=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Initial"))
                    {
                        initial=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("organization"))
                    {
                        organisation=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("country"))
                    {
                        country=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("state"))
                    {
                        state=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("city"))
                    {
                        city=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("pincode"))
                    {
                        pincode=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("datecreated"))
                    {
                        datecreated=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("datemodified"))
                    {
                        datemodified=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("usertype_nm"))
                    {
                        usertype=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("photo1"))
                    {
                        photol=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("followflag"))
                    {
                        following=false;
                    }

                    if(pullParser.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("followdt"))
                    {
                        followdt=false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                eventType=pullParser.next();
                }
            //Log.i("count", ""+ arrayUser.size());



        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

CUstomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data>{

     Context context;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            int text1, ArrayList<String> arrayofString) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context=context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        Data rowItem = getItem(position);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Name);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.name.setText(rowItem.getName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Data.java

```
public class Data {

    String IndividualUser,name,id,initial,organisation,country,state,city,pincode,datecreated,datemodified,usertype,photol,following,followdt;

    public String getindividualUser() {
        return IndividualUser;
    }

    public void setindividualUser(String IndividualUser) {
        this.IndividualUser = IndividualUser;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }}
```

logcat,,

```
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.example.httpwebservices.MainActivity$WebService.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:119)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.example.httpwebservices.MainActivity$WebService.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-20 14:21:28.127: E/AndroidRuntime(968):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 14:21:43.137: I/Process(968): Sending signal. PID: 968 SIG: 9
```

Comment: put your complete logcat

Comment: Can you add your R.layout.activity_main file? Looks like findViewById is returning null

Comment: you have not initialized `arrayUser` `ArrayList` and using it in `for` loop.

Comment: did you make the changes suggested. did you check the edit in my post? does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this

```
  ArrayList<Data> arrayUser; // as a activity class member
```

Then in onCreate

```
  for(int i=0;i<arrayUser.size();i++) // arrayUser is null i guess.
```

Also in parse

```
  public void parse(String xml)
  {
    ArrayList<Data> arrayUser=null;  // local to parse method. delete this
    arrayUser=new ArrayList<Data>();
```

Move the below inside `onPostExecute` so once doInBackground executes and your list is populated you can pass the params to CustomAdapter and update listview.

```
  for(int i=0;i<arrayUser.size();i++)
            {
                data=arrayUser.get(i);
                arrayofString.add(data.getName());
                //Log.i("parsed", ""+data.getName());
            }                               
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item,android.R.id.text1, arrayofString);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Edit:

You have this

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  ListView list;
```

Then in `onCreate` you have

```
  ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.li); // list becomes local to onCreate
```

So Change this

```
    ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.li);
```

to

```
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.li);
```

Comment: actually i have done this. the exception is at list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @AshishPatil check if your list is initialized properly with the right id and is it line 55 `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: @AshishPatil did you check your `list` is initialized properly with right id  and it is not null? post `activtiy_main`

Comment: @AshishPatil use activity context `MainActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` for customadapter param . Other than that your code looks like. Post the updated logcat if it does not work

Comment: @AshishPatil also have you done the changes suggested before. Did you move your code to `onPostExecute`. Post the updated code also

Comment: this is the way it should be done ?               @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    arrayofString=new ArrayList<String>();     
    for(int i=0 ; i< arrayUser.size() ;i++)
    {
     data=arrayUser.get(i);
     arrayofString.add(data.getName());
     Log.i("parsed", ""+data.getName());
    } 
    Log.i("data parsed", ""+arrayofString.size());
    }

Comment: @AshishPatil also move the setadapter code in `onPostExecute`. It looks like you have initialized `list` so it should not be null.

Comment: it should not be null means ?

Comment: @AshishPatil are you sure that is line 55 coz if you have initialized it right and made the changes suggested you should not get NPE. edit your post and paste the updated code and logcat

Comment: @AshishPatil check the edit. you already have a class member `list` as `ListView list` again if you do    `ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.li)` , `list` becomes local to `onCreate`

Comment: yes sir. I have made all the changes you suggested. but still I am unable to get expected output.

Comment: @AshishPatil does it crash now. if that's solved check why you are not getting output i would check the data that populates the list. That could be your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayUser.size();i++)
```

`arrayUser` is null and You get NPE.

You porobably think You initialized it in `WebService.parse()` but

```
ArrayList<Data> arrayUser=null;
arrayUser=new ArrayList<Data>();
```

You are shadowing it with local instance.

Try it by deleting this line in parse() method

```
ArrayList<Data> arrayUser=null;
```

Comment: actually i ave done this. the exception is at list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: there is also the issue that the asynctask is in uncertain state when arrayUser is accessed.

Comment: @njzk2 what do you mean by uncertain state ? please suggest something if possible.

Comment: by uncertain state I mean that there is no a priori knowledge of wether the task is finished, or even started

Answer (score 0):

If the `list.setAdapter(adapter);` is causing the `null pointer exception`, which could indicate the `list` object is null.

`list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.li);`

which indicates that your `content view R.layout.activity_main` doesnt contain the `List view R.id.li`.

Recheck whether your `activity_main.xml` has `List view R.id.li`